# How to Ignore Invalid Input When Creating New Object?

Tags: java

I have a simple problem - create a Dog object with a weight more than 0 and less than 500 and a name. However, I'm spacing on how I can ignore input that isn't valid while printing everything else that IS valid. This is my code so far:

```
//Dog dogFail = new Dog("Grimes", 501); is suppposed to be ignored
public class Dog{
    private String name;
    private double weight;

    public Dog(String myName, double myWeight){
        if(myWeight > 0 && myWeight<500){
            name = myName;
            weight = myWeight;
        }
        else{
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Your dog must weigh between 0 and 500 pounds");
        }
    }

public String toString(){
        return "This dog is named " + name + " and weighs " + weight + " pounds";
    }
```

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: why do you want to allow somebody to create an invalid object? Invalid object are toxic, throwing exception in the constructor is the way to go.

Comment: Well what weight should the dog have if you say the weight is -5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your code currently stands, you do not need to ignore incorrect output at the `toString` stage, since you already handle and reject incorrect input in the constructor.

Imagine that `Dog dogFail = new Dog("Grimes", 501);` is run. In that case, `(myWeight > 0 && myWeight<500)` is false, and so we go to the `else` in the constructor, which throws an `IllegalArgumentException`. At this point, `dogFail` isn't getting constructed. Either the code calling the constructor catches the exception, or your program will end in an error.

If you did want to handle the invalid input at the `toString` stage, you could choose to allow one to use the constructor with an invalid weight by getting rid of the if-else structure and the throw, and checking in the `toString` method:

```
public Dog(String myName, double myWeight){
    name = myName;
    weight = myWeight;

}

public String toString(){
    if(myWeight>0 && myWeight<500) {
        return "This dog is named " + name + " and weighs " + weight + " pounds";
    } else {
        return "This dog is named " + name + " and has an invalid weight entered.";
    }
}
```

Comment: So to clarify, there is no way of ignoring the fact that the weight goes over and not create that object, going over to some other Dog dogNext = new etc.?

 As it stands, the code throws the exception, but it doesn't print out the other valid dog objects.

Comment: @AndrewtheProgrammer I'm not sure exactly what you want. Do you want the weight to be set to some default value if it's invalid? Then just do `weight = [some value]` in the `else`.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity - ideally, I want my code ignore invalid entries and simply not create an object. For example, if I attempted to create dog1 with "Joe" and 10 pounds along with dogFail, dogFail would not exist (because it's weight isn't valid), but dog1 would be fine and could later be printed out, etc.

Comment: @AndrewtheProgrammer It wouldn't create an object since you throw the exception. Please edit your original question to show how you are calling the constructor exactly.

Comment: I was editing the OP and it hit me how this can be solved. Cheers, thanks for the help!

Comment: @AndrewtheProgrammer Not a problem. Thanks for asking a well-written question and following up!

Answer (score 1):

IMHO in this specific situation throwing in the constructor is by far the best option, however, it is worth noting that you can achieve what you want using the [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)

```
public interface Dog {
    public void makeSound();
}

public class NormalDog implements Dog {
    public void makeSound() {
        System.out.println("woof!");
    }
}

public class NullDog implements Dog {
    public void makeSound() {

    }
}

public class FactoryDog {
    Dog createDog(String name, int weight){
        if (isNormalDog(name,weight))
           return new NormalDog(name,weight);
        return new NullDog();
    }
}
```

It is important to notice, that you don't have invalid object (basically a state that breaks the contract of your class) floating around using this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can either follow what you have done with the exception model or simply initialise `Dog` object to have some kind of default value. Assuming all puppies have a minimum weight requirement, you can assign a minimum weight, for example, 3lbs to every `Dog` instance unless their weight is reassigned "Correctly" via the constructor or getter/setter. In this way, you can still instantiate a `Dog`, but as a baby dog.

A lot of users would probably talk against using exception with the constructor but it's legal from coding viewpoints - in fact, if you throw an exception (i.e. you object initialisation fails, it's ready for GC anyway.  You have presented a scenario where using a validator for your `Dog` object is the right thing to do. You can write a class to validate this:

```
public class DogValidator { /* this may extend some abstract validator */

public DogValidator() {
    super();
}

public boolean validatedDog(Dog dog) { /* You can even modify this class to have exclusions e.g. what not to validate (and then use java reflection to invoke methods - may be too advance for what you want to do */
    double weight = dog.getWeight();

    if(weight > 0 && weight < 500) {
         return true;
    } else {
         return false;
    }

}

}
```

Ideally, you would be using these kinds of validators to validate your object's data sanity and integrity. The class above can be improved to have even stricter validation e.g. data type double/float, dog colours etc.

Comment: This is a neat way of working with it and basically what I did. Thanks a bunch